# Memory and CPU usage during a denial of service attack. How to understand the data?

Tags: webserver, denial-of-service

The Debian crontab file that is a **web server** Apache has the line:

```
  */2   *       *       *       *       echo -e "`date`\n\n`free` \n\n`vmstat`\n" >> /home/hacker/free_vmstat_output.txt
```

I extracted the following data from 2 different moments:

```
-e  Mon Apr 10 08:12:01 -03 2017 

              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1271608     143388    1128220       4884      15052      53916
-/+ buffers/cache:      74420    1197188
Swap:       496636          0     496636 

 procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 1128220  15052  53916    0    0    38    23   53   87  1  0 99  0  0




-e  Mon Apr 10 09:51:01 -03 2017 

              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1271608     340384     931224       8980      34348     212528
-/+ buffers/cache:      93508    1178100
Swap:       496636          0     496636 

 procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 930248  34348 212528    0    0    23   108 1635  685  1  6 93  0  0
```

One of the time is before one attack and the other during a denial of service attack. How can I compare CPU and memory usage before the attack and after the attack?